# Why Kafka KTable is missing entries?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a single instance java application that uses KTable from Kafka Streams. Until recently I could retrieve all data using KTable when suddenly some of the messages seemed to vanish. There should be ~33k messages with unique keys there.

When I want to retrieve messages by key I don't get some of the messages. I use ReadOnlyKeyValueStore to retrieve messages:

```
final ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> store = ((KafkaStreams)streams).store(storeName, QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
store.get(key);
```

These are the configuration settings I set to the KafkaStreams.

```
final Properties config = new Properties();
config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_SERVER_CONFIG, serverId);
config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, applicationId);
config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
config.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
config.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericAvroSerde.class);
config.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericAvroSerde.class);
config.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 0);
```

**Kafka**: 0.10.2.0-cp1
**Confluent**: 3.2.0

Investigations brought me to some very worrying insights. Using REST Proxy I manually read partitions and found out that some offsets return error.

Request:
`/topics/{topic}/partitions/{partition}/messages?offset={offset}`

```
{
    "error_code": 50002,
    "message": "Kafka error: Fetch response contains an error code: 1"
}
```

No client, neither java nor command line however return any error. They just skip over the <del>faulty</del> missing messages resulting in missing data in KTables. Everything was fine and without notice it seems that somehow some of the messages got corrupt.

I have two brokers and all the topics have the replication factor of 2 and are fully replicated. Both brokers separately return the same. Restarting brokers makes no difference.

- **What could possibly be the cause?**
- **How to detect this case in a client?**

Comment: I have not idea what `StoreManager` is -- that's not part of Kafka Streams. Do you use windowed or non-windowed KTable? What version of Kafka Streams do you use?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax sorry my mistake I made the question more precise.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That sounds really strange. "they just skip over the faulty messages resulting in missing data" -- this sound like also super strange -- AFAIK, consumers don't have a built-in mechanism for "stepping over" messages. Maybe you should ask at the Kafka user list http://kafka.apache.org/contact (this might even be a bug...) -- It seems not to be a Kafka Streams issues though, as Kafka Streams internally just used Kafka Consumer -- this, if the Consumer behaves strange, there is nothing Kafka Streams can work around this.

Comment: Could the messages that vanished have been deleted because of either log compaction or exceeding the configured retention period?

Comment: @HansJespersen shamefully I must admit that the problem was that simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [default Kafka Broker](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs) config key `cleanup.policy` is set to `delete`. Set it to `compact` to keep the latest message for each key. [See compaction](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#compaction).

Deletion of old messages does not change the minimum offset so trying to retrieve message below it causes an error. The error is very vague. The Kafka Streams client will start reading messages from minimum offset so there is no error. The only visible effect is missing data in KTables.

While the application is running thanks to the [caches](http://docs.confluent.io/3.2.0/streams/developer-guide.html#memory-management) all data might still be available even after messages are deleted from Kafka itself. They will vanish after cleanup.